# My Bootstrap Navbar works fine on Desktop, but on Mobile it overlaps the text in the body. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[As seen here](https://share.unixfy.me/anljcwlk.jpg), the Navbar overlaps the text in the body. How can I fix this? [This is what it looks like on desktop](https://share.unixfy.me/dkpyhum5.png).

Here is my code for the Navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">

  <!-- Logo -->
     
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
     
     <img src="black_hole.jpg" alt="logo" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">
     </a>
     


  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="beermoney.html">BeerMoney Routine</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:(my_email_here)@gmail.com">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Then the rest of the code is the body text.

Any help is appreciated. I'm going on vacation, so I will try to respond to your comments the best I can, but no guarantees.

([All Code here](https://share.unixfy.me/0r56bq4q.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `.fixed-top` class from `<nav>` element to show the content all the time. So you can also remove the `margin-top: 90px;` (or adjust the value) to remove / adjust the gap between navigation and content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Home</title>    
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainClass.css">    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>
    
    <!-- navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
       <img src="black_hole.jpg" alt="logo" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
     
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="beermoney.html">BeerMoney Routine</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:nickbthesaint@gmail.com">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <h3>Who Am I?</h3>
        <p>My name is theITguy, and I am a video editor, student, and an active member of the 3D Printing community.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

In case you want to use the fixed navigation, you have to add support for the responsive navgation so you can toggle on mobile.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Home</title>    
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainClass.css">    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>
    
    <!-- navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
       <img src="black_hole.jpg" alt="logo" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
     
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="beermoney.html">BeerMoney Routine</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:nickbthesaint@gmail.com">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 90px;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <h3>Who Am I?</h3>
        <p>My name is theITguy, and I am a video editor, student, and an active member of the 3D Printing community.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```